# Trouble with C unit conversion

Tags: c, type-conversion, unsigned

I am currently developing an `Android` application which uses a `native C library.` I am very unfamiliar with C, and am having some conversion problems. I know that the problem has something to do with signed/unsigned numbers, but cannot figure out what I need to do to fix this.

The C library works fine on its own, and produces the correct results. However when I port it back to Android, only the positive values are correct. The negative values are returned as 256 minus the value.

For example:

```
 8 -> 8
 5 -> 5
 1 -> 1
 0 -> 0
-3 -> 253
-5 -> 251
-8 -> 248
```

This is what the C code looks like when it assigns the value:

```
BYTE *parms;
WORD __stdcall GetValue(BYTE what, long *val){

    char myStringParmsOne[255];
    sprintf( myStringParmsOne, "parms[1]=%d", parms[1] );
    LOG_INFO( myStringParmsOne );

    char myStringIsG[255];
    sprintf( myStringIsG, "API_isG=%d",API_isG );
    LOG_INFO( myStringIsG );

    char myStringCharParmsB[255];
    sprintf( myStringCharParmsB, "(char)parms[1]=%d", (char)parms[1] );
    LOG_INFO( myStringCharParmsB );

    *val=(char)parms[1]-(API_isG?11:0);
}
```

The `LOG_INFO` statements print the values to `LogCat`. Below I have values when the program is run and a value of `-3` is expected.

```
The first **parms[1]=%d** statement returns **parms[1]=253**

The second **API_isG=%d** statement returns **API_isG=0**

The third **(char)parms[1]=%d** statement returns **(char)parms[1]=253**
```

The BYTE and WORD types are defined as follows:

```
typedef unsigned char BYTE;
typedef unsigned short WORD;
```

The wrapper function I use to send this value back to Java is shown below:

```
long Java_my_package_Model_00024NativeCalls_GetValueJava( JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, WORD what) {
    long c;
    int j = GetValue( what, &c );
    if( j == 0 ) {
        return c;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

The `GetValue` method is used all the time, but only this individual call gives me problems with negative numbers, it works with other calls. I have tried the two following things for my wrapper function:

```
long Java_my_package_Model_00024NativeCalls_GetValueJava( JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, WORD what) {
    long c;
    int j = GetValue( what, &c );
    if( j == 0 ) {
        return (signed char)c;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

The casting of the return value above provides me with a proper return value. However, all of the other calls to this function for other values are completely haywire.

```
long Java_my_package_Model_00024NativeCalls_GetValueJava( JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, WORD what) {
    long c;
    int j = GetValue( what, &c );
    if( j == 0 ) {
        return (signed long)c;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

The above casting of the return value changed nothing.

Comment: That's because `BYTE` is unsigned, and the hardware uses two's compliment representation of negatives.

Comment: Can you tell for which hardware architecture our are building your application for?

Comment: @mathk It is custom, nothing that is available on the open market.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you are putting an unsigned char (IIRC in NDK char is unsigned by default) inside a long. If the value you put inside the long was signed then the compiler would have changed also the sign bit of the long.

Try to change the cast from

```
*val=(char)parms[1]-(API_isG?11:0);
```

to

```
*val=(long)((signed char)parms[1]-(API_isG?11:0));
```

(not sure if the (long) cast is required, maybe the cast to (signed char) is enough.

Comment: char is signed by definition there is no need of signed here.

Comment: Thanks, this helped fix the parameter I was having trouble with, but now a few others are acting funny. It might be something completely unrelated but I won't know until I get home tonight to check. I'll accept the answer tomorrow when I know for sure.

Comment: @mathk: Not true in C.

Comment: In C, it is up to the compiler to decide whether `char` is signed or unsigned. If you need `char` to be signed, you need to explicitly declare the type as `signed char`.

Answer (score 1):

Change the types from unsigned char/unsigned short to char/short if you want to store signed values.

Comment: Should be `signed char`, as it is implementation defined if `char` is signed or unsigned.

Comment: I am not in the position to change the `BYTE/WORD` types, they are used all over the place. The C library being used is also used for a Palm Pilot program, which works perfectly. This is why I believe it has something to do with porting the value back to Android. Is there a way I can convert the value in the wrapper function?

Comment: I am not sure that it will help the OP as there is a cast happening: `*val=(char)parms[1]-(API_isG?11:0);` My intuition is that there is a confusion at the wrapper level between long in C and long in Java.